# generate url after reload page and checkboxes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I generate a url after checked some checkboxes and I can go to the new url after click on a button,when the page load the options that was clicked are cheked until here all is fine, but what happend if I check in new optionf, the new url is wrong.

my checkboxes are like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="women" data-facet="gender">
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="men" data-facet="gender">
<input type="checkbox"name="occasion" value="beach" data-facet="Occasion">
<input type="checkbox"name="occasion" value="street" data-facet="Occasion">
<input type="checkbox"name="color" value="blue" data-facet="color">
<input type="checkbox"name="color" value="red" data-facet="color">
```

And this is my script to generate the url:

```
$("a#filterLink").on("click", function(){
    var arr = [];
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            arr.push($(this).attr('name')+ '=' +$(this).val())
        }
    });
    var values = arr.join("&");
    var str = window.location.pathname +"?&" + values;

});
```

The button that generate the url is this:

```
<a id="filterLink" class="button ">
        Apply    </a>
```

After reload the page if some of the options was checked (gender men)and I checked the option like `color red`the new url generated is like below:

`/myproducts/?&Men=Men&Men=Men&gender=Men&Men=Men&Men=Men&gender=Men&color=red`

How can I reset or get the new url without the problem of checked options?

Comment: Aside: you can simplify your code by just doing [$(':checkbox').serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of building your query string.

Comment: Not sure if you're asking how to uncheck all boxes after page reload or if you're having a different problem

Comment: @BRogers no, i don't want to uncheck it, my problem is when the page load if i check another option still checked any other the url generated was like a I posted